# Getting an error with my ALTER TABLE syntax

Tags: mariadb, alter-table

Can someone check this syntax for me? I'm getting an error... I need to change `TIME` to `BEGIN_TIME` and then add a column for `END_TIME`. Thanks in advance!

```
ALTER TABLE LABINFO_WARDL.DIM_TIMEPERIOD 
    RENAME COLUMN TIME TO BEGIN_TIME, 
    ADD END_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

Comment: is this a MySQL table?

Comment: Side note .. why not just use MySQL Workbench so you can right click and rename them with a couple clicks?  Download here --> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: This is for a class assignment using MySQL and I'm learning it. :)

Comment: Any time you're "getting an error" you need to [tell us what the error is](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: Sorry for not showing the error... new to this... I found another article showing this exact syntax... here's my error... ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN TIME TO BEGIN_TIME, ADD END_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: Do I need to put TIME in parentheses? (TIME)

Comment: use this character `
It is to the left of the 1 key in the row of numbers on the keyboard.

Comment: its use to wrap around db named things versus this character for strings '

Comment: Like this? ALTER TABLE LABINFO_WARDL.DIM_TIMEPERIOD RENAME COLUMN `TIME` TO BEGIN_TIME, ADD END_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL;

Comment: First part seems right I can't recall but I think on the second thing you have to specify where the new column goes, so there might be an AFTER or BEFORE needed, but you seem to be on the right track.

Comment: Although this is what you need to test your code in, try this link --->
https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: Your code works in MySQL 8.0 ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CVDpzPLV)), but throws error in MySQL 5.7. Documentation of [ALTER TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) for 5.7 shows different syntax, like here: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D1B6F6g5).

Comment: Thank you for the syntax validator... good to know!!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error you shared shows that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. Please be aware these are different products. Although MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, they have both been changing since then, and they are not fully compatible anymore.

Using MariaDB 10.5 or later, the statement you show works with no error.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/iEmddH5u

If I change that dbfiddle to MariaDB 10.4, it reproduces the error you showed in comments.

Here's a tip about syntax errors: make yourself familiar with the reference documentation. I've been using MySQL for over 20 years, and I use the documentation *every day*. Trying to be a programmer without using the manual is a recipe for frustration and failure.

Using Stack Overflow every time you run into a syntax error is a big waste of your time and everyone else's time.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#rename-column says:

> ### RENAME COLUMN
>
> **MariaDB starting with 10.5.2**
>
> From MariaDB 10.5.2, it is possible to rename a column using the
> `RENAME COLUMN` syntax, for example:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE t1 RENAME COLUMN c_old TO c_new;
> ```

It seems that you got the syntax right, but you're using a version of MariaDB 10.4 or earlier, which do not implement that syntax.

You can verify the version of MariaDB you are using by running this query:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

Comment: 10.0.30-MariaDB

Comment: I didn't even realize MariaDB was different from MySQL...

Comment: The MariaDB marketing folks work hard to make you think MariaDB is the same as MySQL. It's why I never use MariaDB. Not because it isn't technically good enough software, but I object to their underhanded marketing.

Comment: By the way, that version you're using, MariaDB 10.0, was released in 2014, and fell out of supported status in 2019. Like any other software that has not been updated, it probably has lots of unfixed security vulnerabilities. Check out the dates of release and end of support here: https://endoflife.date/mariadb

Comment: I'm not surprised at all... this class (and many others like it) has so much old content, it's so annoying...

Comment: 2014 is like back in the dinosaur ages haha

Comment: Well just so you're aware that SQL syntax you try might not work on ten-year-old software. They make new features in every release, as every software maker does, and they do not add those features retroactively to the old versions. So if you get an error like the one you got today, you need to learn how to research the documentation and find out if it's supported in the version of software you're using. This is an important skill for being a programmer!

Comment: @taipei2sc thank people by accepting their answer.